# How to construct a string and run it as a command

Tags: string, matlab, plot

I'm using gramm to plot some data. **Long story short:** I'd like to construct a string based on user input that is then run as a command to call the gramm function.

I have a structure that contains data for a number of samples--the data in each sample contains the intensities for a number of chemical species.

I'm constructing a bar graph that shows the intensity of each chemical species for each sample. In other words, my y axis is intensity, my x axis is chemical species, and my 'color' is sample.

Now I don't want to plot every sample or even every chemical species from each sample. As it stands right now, I have to go through and hard code this. But I'd like to tlel matlab which chemical species and which samples I want plotted.

As of now, this means writing an extremely long command:

```
g=gramm('y', allData.(fileName).intensities, 'x', ...
    allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies, 'color', ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleName,'subset',...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l & ...
    allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Butanal" | ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Butenal" |...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Pentanal" |...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Pentenal" | ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Hexanal" | ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Hexenal" | ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Heptanal" | ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Heptenal"| ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Octanal" | ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Octenal" | ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Nonanal"  | ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Nonenal" | ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Butanedial"| ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Pentanedial"| ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Hexanedial"| ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Heptanedial"| ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Octanedial" | ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleNum <u & allData.(fileName).sampleNum >l ...
    & allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies == "Nonanedial")
```

As you can see, this code plots only a certain subset of samples (those that are between samplenum u and l) and only plots certain chemical species.

What I'd like is to input the specific samples and chemical species I'm interested, and use that input to generate a line of code that calls the gramm function--this without having to hardcode it in as shown above.

Basically, I need to construct a string based on inputs, and then have that string run as a command for calling gramm.

Thank you!

EDIT: Clarification

I want something where a dialog box comes up and asks me to select which samples and chemical species I want. Let's say I choose sample A, B, C and chemical species Propanal and Butanal.

Currently, I'd have to hardcode this in myself:

```
g=gramm('y', allData.(fileName).intensities, 'x', ...
    allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies, 'color', ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleName,'subset',...
    allData.(fileName).sampleName == 'A' &... 
    allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Propanal"
    allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Butanal" | ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleName == 'B' &... 
    allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Propanal"
    allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Butanal" | ...
    allData.(fileName).sampleName == 'C' &... 
    allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Propanal"
    allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Butanal")
```

Instead of having to hard code this, I'd like to make a string that contains all of this, and is then passed as a command.

I think this can be accomplished by using a for loop that concatenates a string to an array for each sampleSame. With this method, I'm able to create a string that says:

constructPlot = "g=gramm('y', allData.(fileName).intensities, 'x', ...
        allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies, 'color', ...
        allData.(fileName).sampleName,'subset',...
        allData.(fileName).sampleName == 'A' &... 
        allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Propanal"
        allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Butanal" | ...
        allData.(fileName).sampleName == 'B' &... 
        allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Propanal"
        allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Butanal" | ...
        allData.(fileName).sampleName == 'C' &... 
        allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Propanal"
        allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies =="Butanal")"

When I type constructPlot it displays the string, but I want it to run as a command rather than as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ismember](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to combine conditions:

```
names = [...
"Butanal"  
"Butenal" 
"Pentanal" 
"Pentenal"  
"Hexanal"  
"Hexenal"  
"Heptanal"  
"Heptenal" 
"Octanal"  
"Octenal"  
"Nonanal"   
"Nonenal"  
"Butanedial"
"Pentanedial"
"Hexanedial"
"Heptanedial"
"Octanedial" 
"Nonanedial"];
condition = allData.(fileName).sampleNum < u & ...
allData.(fileName).sampleNum > l & ...  
ismemeber(allData.(fileName).chemicalSpecies ,names);
```